# IndexedDB Issues with Windows Store App Submission

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10, win-universal-app, indexeddb

We have been trying to submit an update to a Windows Store Desktop/Tablet App for a few weeks now. The app fails to properly initialize when being tested, but we are unable to reproduce any issues locally.

This is a Javascript WebApp, and we are using Cordova to make it cross-platform.

After adding some remote error logging, we have noticed that on testers' machines there is an IndexedDB initialization error.

The code we that seems to fail is:

```
var dbOpenRequest = indexedDB.open('CustomDBName', 1);
```

This seems to fail immediately, and calls our error handler (dbOpenRequest.onerror = ...).

What could cause this?

- We have tried several devices and admin/guest modes on the OS, etc.

Could this be a test machine issue?

- Our previously approved and released app also seems to now have this issue. We tried resubmitting our old app and it failed certification (strange!).

Is there any reason that we are not noticing this on any of our devices? We have tested the app on the following devices using the same build we submitted to the store:

- ASUS T100 Transformer, Win 8.1
- Dell Venue Pro 11, Win 8.1
- Digiland 8" Tablet on Win 8.1
- Misc Surface Tablet
- Several laptops on Windows 8.1 and 10

The closest support issue I've found related to this seems to be an OS issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7771e681-724c-4229-912c-06b627ce4c16/uwphtml-win10-build-10547-javascript-uwp-indexeddb-cannot-be-opened?forum=wpdevelop

Do you have any ideas or suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: You can put the logging in your error handler and tell what is the error ?? If IDB is not opening then it means it has never worked in you app or is it that sometimes and in some specific scenarios you get this step ?? Check http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb to know IDB support for various browsers ..I am assuming your `indexedDB` is actually a variable holding `window.indexedDB` because to open a IDB you need `window.indexedDB.open`

Comment: @hagrawal the error seems to be "UnknownError". This was working perfectly fine for our first submission, which also used IndexedDB and was successfully submitted to the stores.

Comment: If error is "UnknownError" then it doesn't mean you cannot get information out of it .. FYI - you can get hell of the information from error handler using `event.target.error.name`, `event.target.source.name`, `event.target.error.message` etc., which can be crucial for RCA ..

Comment: An unknownerror occurs when something Goes wrong with I/O operations. I don't know if You need To add something To the manifest file To ask permission To use the indexeddb storage.

Comment: @hagrawal, thanks! We are currently logging  event.target.error.name but not source or error.message - I'll look into that.

Comment: @KristofDegrave, I don't think we need to add anything to the manifest file. The indexeddb sample doesn't seem to have anything for it - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/IndexedDB-sample-eb1e95af#content

Comment: You are sure the onupgradeneeded and blocked don't get called? Have you tried opening the indexeddb without providing a version?

Comment: Do lot of logging, as much as you can, in all event listeners like `onsuccess`, `onupgradeneeded`, `onblocked`, `onerror`, and let me know what you get, however trivial it may be but let me know every log details, that's the only way I can try to understand what's gng on .. Also, I would recommend create a very simple demo app (just IDB open and logging in important event handlers) without Cordova and all, and run in your test machine, and see if it works .. If it doesn't they it is very likely to be OS build issue, same as the link you pointed in your question ..

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the indexeddb api trough a webbrowser? or is it done by accessing the files trough the filesystem. I know phonegap normally uses the webbrowser approche, but maybe for performance reasons it is possible to go directly using the file system.

Comment: @KristofDegrave just using the webbrowser methods. I believe windows uses the IE10 engine to render the WinJS apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this time the certification systems had an issue.

The app was finally certified.

Answer (score 2):

I think you get this error because "window" is missing. Have you tried to do the following? (example code from Microsoft site)

```
var hDb = null;

try {

   if (window.indexedDB) {

      var req = window.indexedDB.open("CustomDBName", 1);

      req.onsuccess = function(evt) { 
         hDB = evt.target.result;
      }      

      req.onerror = failureHandler();
      req.onblocked = blockedHandler();

      req.onupgradeneeded = function(evt) {
         createDatabaseObjects(evt.target.result);
      }
   }
} catch(ex) {
   handleException(ex);
}
```

Related information from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj154905(v=vs.85).aspx), [Cordova IndexDB plugin](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-indexedDB).